# How to find folders with broken security on windows files shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

I need to migrate many windows network file shares over the coming months and there is the occasional "super user" who has files so important they stop the folder from inheriting permissions and lock it from even administrators. Are there any good tools that can be run against a file share to find these kind of folders?

Comment: Why do you need to know which folders are locked? You can simply copy them with Robocopy /ZB.

Answer (score 0):

[ShareEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897442.aspx)

[ShareEnum_wsf](http://www.akaplan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/ShareEnum_wsf.txt) source

[NTFS Permissions Analyzer for Active Directory](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/permissions_analyzer_for_active_directory/)